# Clarification about FileWriter

Tags: java, file, io, filewriter

Directly from the related `FileWriter` [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html):

> Whether or not a file is available or may be created depends upon the
>   underlying platform.

Does it mean that it's not guaranteed that:

```
//assume all the exceptions have been taken care of.
    File file = new File("/home/user/Desktop/lol.txt");
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

creates the file even though the file does not exist? I thought it was guaranteed. Do they mean maybe due to priviledge and things?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be unable to create file if you don't have permission to create that file where you're trying to create it.

Look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File)):

> **Throws:**
>
> IOException - if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, **does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason**

You can use the [AccessController#checkPermission(java.security.Permission)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#checkPermission(java.security.Permission)) method and pass [FilePermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilePermission.html) object to check what permissions you have before trying to create a file.

Comment: mm I see so it's safe to say that there are the same limitation of file.createNewFile() right?

Comment: @Rollerball Yes I believe so !